# Calculate the average next-day retention rate of users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that records the login information of users on a website, including ID and login date.

For example:

| id | user_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | 2341 | 2024-01-07 |
| 3 | 2341 | 2024-01-13 |
| 4 | 3412 | 2024-01-20 |
| 5 | 4123 | 2024-01-20 |
| 6 | 4123 | 2024-01-21 |
| 7 | 4123 | 2024-01-22 |
| 8 | 2341 | 2024-01-07 |
| 9 | 2341 | 2024-01-22 |
| 10 | 3412 | 2024-01-20 |
| 11 | 4123 | 2024-01-20 |
| 12 | 4123 | 2024-01-21 |
| 13 | 4123 | 2024-01-22 |
| 14 | 2341 | 2024-01-23 |
| 15 | 2341 | 2024-01-25 |
| 16 | 3412 | 2024-01-20 |

**Note that the table will contain duplicate data** because users may log in multiple times a day.

I now want to calculate the **average next day retention rate** of users, for the example data above, the average next-day retention rate would be **0.3**.

I tried the following query, but the result I got was 0.4. I think my idea should be right, but I don't know why the result is wrong.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is or give me a correct answer? (I use PieCloudDB Database. If you haven’t heard of it, you can use PostgreSQL instead. PieCloudDB is compatible with PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (q2.user_id,q2.date))*1.0/COUNT(DISTINCT (q1.user_id,q1.date)) as avg_ret
from login as q1 
left join login as q2
on q1.user_id=q2.user_id 
and q2.date = q1.date + interval '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by `COUNT(DISTINCT q2.user_id, q2.date)` including `NULL, NULL` as one of the distinct combinations. The following query produces the correct result of 0.3:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT (q2.user_id, q2.date))
    FILTER (WHERE q2.date IS NOT NULL) * 1.0
  /
 COUNT(DISTINCT (q1.user_id, q1.date)) AS avg_ret
FROM
  login AS q1
  LEFT JOIN login AS q2
    ON q1.user_id = q2.user_id
      AND q2.date = q1.date + INTERVAL '1 day';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried deduplicating the id and date separately and the result I got was 0.3. (Tested on the pieclouddb database cloud platform)

```
SELECT COUNT(q2.user_id)*1.0 / COUNT(q1.user_id) AS avg_ret
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, date 
  FROM login) AS q1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, date 
  FROM login) AS q2
ON q1.user_id = q2.user_id 
AND q2.date = q1.date + interval '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to solve this is to avoid the `LEFT JOIN` and use `CASE` and `EXISTS` logic.

The "problem" with `LEFT JOIN` is you need to handle `NULL` values, as well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78236423/18794826). This is not required when using `EXISTS`.

At the other side, some people prefer using `JOIN` over subqueries and sometimes, the performance is better. I think both ways are fine, just try out.

```
WITH login_sub AS
  (SELECT
    DISTINCT user_id, login_date 
   FROM login)
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM login_sub l2 
     WHERE 
       login_sub.user_id = l2.user_id
       AND login_sub.login_date + INTERVAL '1 day' = l2.login_date)
  THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS avg_ret
FROM login_sub;
```

This  query returns 0.3, see this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xiAzyNPB) with your data

Note: I renamed the column `date` to `login_date` in my answer because `date` is a key word and it's recommended to avoid key words as table name or as column name.